# Correlation between subsequence of time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

For some time-series prediction, I would like to use the correlation between the subsequence of time-series. But I'm confused that Does it really interpretable to use the correlation between subsequence because generally the correlation between dimensions is used and correlation is used in multivariate time-series.
Let T be univariate time series and t1,t2 are subsequences of T. Can we use correlation for some prediction?

My intuition: As the values are time-dependent, the current window has an impact on the next window. So finding correlation is meaningful.

Any kind of answer or reference is appreciable.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [autocorrelation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)? In some ways it is even a wider concept that finding correlation between subsequences. Also your intuition is correct. Univariate time series models use *repetitive patterns* in time series for prediction.

Comment: @Dayne Thank you so much

Comment: @Dayne Can I use Pearson's correlation?

Comment: Autocorrelation for a stationary series at a particular lag is basically pearson correlation only.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I got it

Comment: @Dayne: That looks like an answer. Can you write it up, formally?

Comment: Sure will do :)